# Google sheet formula ArrayFormula dont work

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

```
iferror(INDEX('All'!I2:I, MATCH(A3,'All'!J2:J,0)),"")
```

This is my formula I want to convert to arrayformula but it doesn't work.

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(INDEX('All'!I2:I, MATCH(A3,'All'!J2:J,0)),""))
```

Please send me correct formula

Comment: It would be best to tell us what you're trying to achieve with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"To convert to arrayformula" usually means that, whereas the formula used to operate on one value, now we instead want it to operate on an array of input values.

From your example malfunctioning arrayformula,

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(INDEX('All'!I2:I, MATCH(A3,'All'!J2:J,0)),""))
```

The MATCH, and IFERROR functions work alright in an ARRAYFORMULA, but it seems INDEX does not. I'll assume you're trying to extend the classic INDEX MATCH pattern to return multiple values. Use a VLOOKUP instead, as they work fine inside ARRAYFORMULA.

You haven't provided sufficient info in your question to specify what you want, but my best guess is that a working formula might resemble:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3:A, {All!J2:J, All!I2:I}, 2, FALSE)))
```

Note that [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) ridiculously only offers searching in the first column of input and returning a matching row's cell from some subsequent column. Since the opposite is needed here, the above formula feeds it an array literal, assembled from just the two required columns in reverse order.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this gave the same result as the formula I wrote. Only the first row can be returned with this formula.

Comment: Mea culpa! I hopped over to a Sheets file, somehow convinced myself INDEX works in ARRAYFORMULA, and wrote it up. It does not. @EdgarMagtaghyan Please check the answer again, as it has been mostly replaced.

Comment: Yeeees !!!! It worked, you surprised me, thank you very very much !!!